# Is there any need to refresh token explicitly when accessing drive API's using google libraries via Service Account?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, service-accounts, drive

I have an application written in Java that uploads files to Google drive using google SDK for drive API , via a service account. I want to understand that do I really need to explicitly handle the access token expiry issue because as per my understanding the SDK itself checks and refreshes the token if it expires.
I can be wrong, but I didn't found any documentation regarding the token refresh for service accounts.
I have attached the code for Google Authorization:

```
  public void init() throws Exception {
        // consider gAuth is a google_scret.json file
        gAuth = SecretsUtil.getSecret("auth");
        credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(gAuth.getBytes()))
                .createScoped(DriveScopes.all());
        requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
        log.info("Google Auth Service Initialized");
        
    }

    public HttpRequestInitializer getCredential() {
        return requestInitializer;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*No need, this is handled for you.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation:

> A service account uses an OAuth 2.0 flow that does not require human authorization. Instead, it uses a key file that only your application can access.

The idea is that a Service Account will continue to run, doing what it needs to, without the need for any interaction by a person so the client libraries handle this for you.

> Access tokens issued by the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server expire one hour after they are issued. When an access token expires, then the application should generate another JWT, sign it, and request another access token.

#### References:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [Understanding service accounts | Cloud IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)
- [Service accounts | Cloud IAM Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)